# How to speed up MongoDB's Map Reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've to perform a map reduce operation with a clustering algorithm of a large amount of data.
I've choose MongoDB for its scalability, great docs, BSon documents storage and many other great features.

But, the map-reduce operation is ***too slow***. Only one core of my quadcore CPU is used.

[image: CPU utilization]
[image: Disk Utilization]

I read [this document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work) and I understand that is a JavaScript's fault.

> "Only one thread in the mongod process executes Javascript at a time"

How can I improve that? Improving IO speed?

- SSD storage may be useful?
- Load the whole MongoDB's data on RAM?

Otherwise bottleneck is *only* the CPU and the mono-thread algorithm, so I have to re-write my algorithm in another language, outside Mongo, to take advantage of multi-threading and multi-processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Otherwise bottleneck is only the CPU and the mono-thread algorithm

The issue is that there is no parallelization of work while Mongo is using Spidermonkey as its js engine.  There is a long term plan to [move to V8](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407) to allow multi-threaded execution of js tasks, but it won't make the next release (2.2).

Some of the slowness with map/reduce will be improved in 2.2 for people who will be able to switch to the new [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) instead of map/reduce.  Unfortunately it doesn't sound like that will help you since you are using custom algorithm and not just aggregation computations.

Answer (score 0):

Map-reduce is like an appendix added to MongoDB at some point. If you are looking for ascalable MR options with MongoDB then look into the MongoDB Hadoop integration. The MR implementation of MongoDB is too limited and scary in order to use it for scalable enterprise solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The concurrency section of the MongoDB map-reduce docs suggest that multiple map-reduces will run in parallel, though they will block each other at times:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#map-reduce-concurrency

Your question implies that your processing algorithm is a single map-reduce operation, so if you are able to split that into multiple map-reduce operations you may see some benefit.

However, if there's no IOwait and a single processor is maxed out then it seems unlikely.